# How Do I Search For AD Groups In Shiro Without A System User?

Tags: active-directory, shiro

I am using Shiro to authenticate against Active Directory using `ActiveDirectoryRealm`. This part works fine and I can log in.

However, I am unable to search for Roles/Groups.

I suspect it is because I do not have a `systemUsername/systemPassword` configured. I don't have that option either.

If I use an application like [LdapAdmin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/) I have to put my email and password in the authentication fields in order to connect and browse.

[image: LdapAdmin Connection Properties]

When I use Spring Security I don't have to supply any such "systemUser". I'm guessing that it uses the same username/password credentials that I supplied to log in.

How do I configure Shiro to do the same?

See below for a rough version of what my `shiro.ini` looks like.

```
adRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
adRealm.url = ldap://my.ad.url:389
adRealm.principalSuffix=@example.com
adRealm.systemUsername= 
adRealm.systemPassword= 
adRealm.searchBase = "OU=org,DC=example,DC=com"
adRealm.groupRolesMap = "CN=admins":"admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it does not support this.

The current implementation could be improved to query role information when checking when authenticating. (which is the only point where the realm has access to the user's credentials)

Comment: Can something be sub-classed/overridden to provide this functionality?

Comment: Absolutely, take a look at this [thread](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-a-custom-principal-object-td1090270.html).  It doesn't solve your exact problem, but using that approach is one way to solve it.  
In your case, you could create a custom principal at login, query for roles, and call some sort of setRoles() method on your principal.  Then override `getAuthroizationInfo()` and build the `AuthenticationInfo` object with the result of your custom `getRoles()` of your principal.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I made a custom realm (extending ActiveDirectoryRealm) to search for the roles during log in then accessed them directly later instead of trying to search using the system user.

Salient code is below, full code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/opticyclic/shiro-spring-examples/blob/master/ms-active-directory-custom/src/main/java/com/github/opticyclic/shiro/realm/CustomActiveDirectoryRealm.java).

```
  /**
   * This is called during the log in process.
   * Authenticate but also store the roles/groups on a custom principal
   */
  @Override
  protected AuthenticationInfo queryForAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token, LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
    SimpleAuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = (SimpleAuthenticationInfo)super.queryForAuthenticationInfo(token, ldapContextFactory);
    PrincipalCollection principals = authenticationInfo.getPrincipals();

    UsernamePasswordToken usernamePasswordToken = (UsernamePasswordToken)token;
    String username = usernamePasswordToken.getUsername();
    String userPrincipalName = getUserPrincipalName(token);

    Set<String> roleNames;
    // Binds using the username and password provided by the user.
    LdapContext ldapContext = null;
    try {
      ldapContext = ldapContextFactory.getLdapContext(userPrincipalName, (usernamePasswordToken.getPassword()));
      roleNames = getRoleNamesForUser(username, ldapContext);
    } finally {
      LdapUtils.closeContext(ldapContext);
    }

    List<UserPrincipal> customPrincipals = getCustomPrincipals(userPrincipalName, roleNames);

    //Merge the custom principals and the main principals
    SimplePrincipalCollection principalCollection = new SimplePrincipalCollection(customPrincipals, CustomActiveDirectoryRealm.class.getSimpleName());
    principalCollection.addAll(principals);

    authenticationInfo.setPrincipals(principalCollection);

    return authenticationInfo;
  }


  /**
   * This is called during checks for hasRole.
   * Use the roles that we found on login
   */
  @Override
  protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals, LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
    UserPrincipal availablePrincipal = (UserPrincipal)getAvailablePrincipal(principals);
    Set<String> roleNames = availablePrincipal.getRoleNames();

    return buildAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
  }
```